# Is this the easiest way to make an 'animated' text?

Tags: c#, winforms, animation, text

I'm trying to add a "*Loading...*" text (or other such text) in my application.  But is this the easiest & shortest way of doing it?

I am using this code at the moment:

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (label1.Text == "Loading")
        label1.Text = "Loading .";
    else if (label1.Text == "Loading .")
        label1.Text = "Loading . .";
    else if (label1.Text == "Loading . .")
        label1.Text = "Loading . . .";
    else if (label1.Text == "Loading . . .")
        label1.Text = "Loading";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't run the code, but I hope you get the idea.

```
string[] messages = {
    "loading",
    "loading .",
    "loading ..",
    "loading ..."
};

int turn = 0;

private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    label1.Text = messages[turn++];
    turn %= messages.Length;
}
```

Comment: 'System.Array' does not contain a definition for 'lenght' and no extension method 'Lenght' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Array' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: It should be `Length` and not `length`; I've edited @SAM post to fix it; anyway look for my answer here around: it gives you a _more compact_ solution

Comment: Couldn't resist: `var messages = Enumerable.Range(0, 5).Select(n => "Loading" + new String('.', n)).ToArray();`

Comment: @jyrka: ok, but you asked for the _easiest_ and _shortest_ method for accomplishing the requested task... and mine is, at least, the _shortest_ :) Anyway, I am glad to know that you're happy with SAM solution: the most important thing on SO is to help people with their problems... it SAM's answer is good for you, then it is good for me too.

Comment: @MorixDev I did look at your code before SAM's , but the code only made 2 dots after "Loading", tho when i change the number from 3 to 4 that wasnt a problem. Last thing was that your code put dots together like this: "..." , but i need it to be more 'visible' like this ". . ."

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
private int numberOfPoints = 0;

private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   int maxPoints = 3;
   label.Text = "Loading" + new string('.', numberOfPoints);
   numberOfPoints = (numberOfPoints + 1) % (maxPoints + 1);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Shorter way for your approach

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   label1.Text = (label1.Text == "Loading . . .") ? "Loading" : (label1.Text + " .");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest something similar:

```
private int counter = 0;

private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    label1.Text = string.Format("Loading{0}", new string('.', (++counter) % 3));
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I dont know which technologie you use, but in WPF, Silverlight, WP, Win8, etc. You should use `Storyboards`.

[Storyboards Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742868%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) :

> This topic shows how to use Storyboard objects to organize and apply animations. It describes how to interactively manipulate Storyboard objects and describes indirect property targeting syntax.

sample :

```
<Storyboard>
   <DoubleAnimation 
     Storyboard.TargetName="MyRectangle"
     Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width"
     From="100" To="200" Duration="0:0:1" />

  <ColorAnimation 
    Storyboard.TargetName="MySolidColorBrush"
    Storyboard.TargetProperty="Color"
    From="Blue" To="Red" Duration="0:0:1" />  
</Storyboard>
```

For WinForms, you can find your answer [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/24664/Animation-on-Windows-Forms).

> This article is meant to explain how to add animations to a Windows Form. The first section will briefly explain the process behind by designing a Windows Form. Next will be an example of drawing on a Form using the Graphics class. Finally, the article will conclude with code that can either be compiled on the DOS prompt of the .NET Framework, or built using the separate files that comprise the Visual Studio project.

Comment: I am using C# Windows Forms Application.

Comment: This techno is to old for my answer. You can find your answer [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/24664/Animation-on-Windows-Forms)